# Calling Oracle Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex

I need to call oracle function within java script so that i can get the values from database how can i do that
here I have hardcoded value 
$("label[for=P101_LANG]>span").text("لغة")
  $x("P101_LOGIN").value = "تسجيل الدخول";

Answer (score 2):

You can't call any Database directly from JavaScript like here you are trying to call oracle function from javascript. JavaScript work on client side and you need a server side language to call/interact from database.

You must have to use any server side language like PHP, JSP, ASP etc to call DB. than you can use ajax to call server side page from javascript and from server side page you can call DB function.

Comment: Can i get a simple example to do this process

Comment: See this for an example of PHP(server side), Mysql(DB side) and JavaScript  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp